# T-SQL is "Turing complete": What does this mean, exactly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

From Wikipedia:

> T-SQL expands on the SQL standard to include procedural programming,
>   local variables, various support functions for string processing, date
>   processing, mathematics, etc. and changes to the DELETE and UPDATE
>   statements. These additional features make Transact-SQL Turing
>   complete.[citation needed]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL

Can someone here explain in simple terms what Turing-completeness is and why the "SQL standard" is Turing-incomplete as opposed to the expansion T-SQL which is Turing-complete?

Comment: This is from information theory and one usually gets this when studying CS.  Use [the wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) for the details since the answer is far too complex to put it here in a few sentences.

Comment: Actually with recursive queries (common table expressions) standard SQL is also turing complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Turing Complete" has a technical meaning, but the term is usually used as a shorthand for "you can write code to do arbitrary logic in this" (such as business logic) as opposed to "you can only use this for limited tasks" (like selecting XML nodes with XPath).

No actually existing modern language is *truly* Turing complete because Turing-completeness requires infinite memory, which modern computers do not have.

As explained in the Wikipedia entry, all that is really needed for a turing-complete language is the ability to store and retrieve variables, and some sort of conditional execution based on retrieved values. Such a language can be exceedingly difficult to use. Joke languages have been created on this basis.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness

To summarize: A language is Turing complete if it can compute every function that a Turing machine can. Alternatively, if it can be used to write an emulator of a single-tape Turing machine.

Comment: "No modern language is truly Turing complete" -- I think you mean no implementation of any modern language, right? I don't think the claim that T-SQL the language is Turing-complete is incorrect, even technically.

Comment: @hvd, no, I don't. C is not turing complete because it defines the size of a pointer as finite, and hence the size of addressable memory is also finite, so incompleteness is baked into the language. TSQL is not turing complete because it defines the maxiumum number of rows a table can contain (indirectly via ROW_NUMBER), so that's not infinite either.

Comment: Yes, the size of a C pointer is finite, but it doesn't need to be the same for every program, so purely theoretically from the language's POV, it could be however large the program being compiled needs pointers to be. From the implementation's POV, it's of course different. It's the same with T-SQL. Yes, `ROW_NUMBER()` returns `bigint`, which has a finite range, but is that range part of the T-SQL language, or part of Microsoft's implementation of it? I'd say the latter.

Comment: @hvd, in the case of C, since the pointer size is defined as finite, that means while you can in theory always create a new implementation which can address any chosen size of memory, no single implementation can address an arbitrary size of memory. So no implementation can be turing complete.

Comment: Different programs on the same implementation are allowed to have different pointer sizes. It doesn't require creating a new implementation for each program, although it would have a similar effect. No real-world implementation does this, of course, but that's not relevant here. :)